# How did Zoom learn to use his powers in the Arrowverse?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, powers

Zoom in the Arrowverse was not taught by anyone how to use his superpowers. So how did he learn to use his superpowers such as superspeed, lightning blasts, etc.?

Comment: The superpowered people who turn up and use their powers without having been taught.

Comment: https://screenrant.com/arrowverse-superheroes-list-batwoman-flash-supergirl-legends/ may be useful for a list of candidates.

Comment: There are plenty of instances across the Arrowverse that show metahumans accidentally discovering their powers, and learning their powers by trial and error.    

Supergirl (and by extension, Superman), for example, had her powers a very long time prior to becoming superheros. They grew with powers, and learned to control them.

Comment: @Roberto I'm unsure what you mean. Are you saying that they learn to use their powers by learning to control them? I'm not understanding your train of thought.

Comment: @Smith Yes. Barry (The Flash) discovered the speed force by accident when he was running extremely fast. He discovered time travel in the same way. Etc, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is something like a frame challenge rather than an in-universe answer, but felt unsuitable for a comment...

There are a few things we could mean by "learning to use powers":

1. Discovering that the powers exist
2. Learning to activate the powers on-demand
3. Learning to use the powers in a useful way
4. Learning to make *the best possible* use of the

Now consider "the power of walking" which most humans have:

1. As infants develop a sense of self, they learn that they have legs.
2. Through curiosity and experimentation, they learn to control their legs.
3. Once they have that control, they start applying it to useful goals - often crawling first, then balancing, then walking. They might have some encouragement from adults, or mimic what they see, but they would probably invent walking on their own eventually, *because it's useful*.
4. Someone who can walk might train to become an athlete. Often, they will solicit advice on this, which might be from another athlete, or just someone who can help them measure their progress; but even on their own, they can practice, and experiment with ways to improve their technique.

So, the likely answer is that superheroes can follow the same steps: make use of encouragement and training if it's available, but mostly just experiment and practice.

Answer (score 2):

### Anger

In Season 2, Episode 23, Zoom says

> Use your anger, just like I did

Source: [Transcript](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=27364)

This implies that Zoom uses his powers through focusing his rage. His backstory is rather ripe for producing anger, since his father killed his mother and his father had Zoom watch while he killed her.

Looking at Zooms use of his powers, he knows how to throw lightning, and he knows how to make clones, but he usually just slashes his opponents and runs really fast, or uses his super strength. Controlling how much strength you put into you strikes, running fast, and slashing with fingers isn't that foreign to humans.   After all, you don't throw the door really hard when you open it, but you will punch a bag a lot harder. So while it is unclear based on Canon how he learned to make clones and throw lightning, most of his use of his powers are comprehensible to most people, and he taps into his anger to use them.

Also, it isn't that hard when you are angry to punch the heck out of a pillow.

Answer (score 1):

In general, [meta-humans](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Meta-humans) in the Arrowverse seem to have some intuitive understanding of their powers that lets them use it, like being able to squeeze a newly attained muscle. Barry doesn't have to speak some mystic word to move quickly. The Turtle doesn't need to push a button to stop time. They simply did it intuitively, and fairly readily, when instinct prompted them to. After that, it's all about learning the parameters of the power, training to expand those parameters, and learning little tricks that one can do with it. If a human suddenly gained the ability (or realized it) to suck air and other fluids into their body, they become [*Le Pétomane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A9tomane). If you attach a device to transmit a camera signal to the visual cortex of a blind person, they learn to hear. And once you have an ability, you start to learn new things you can do with it.

### Metahuman powers cheat a bit

In real life, this adaptation to suddenly gaining an ability tends to be much more muted. Neural plasticity is highest when we are very young due to a combination of a lack of former knowledge to overcome and a surfeit of time (what else are you going to do as a baby other than listen to every phoneme and sound in the world and try to make them have sense?), as well as a great forgiveness of mistakes (children take *years* to figure out grammar and yet we look askance on an adult who takes a month or so to really get the hang of subjunctive case). And in cases where people have been granted a new sense, they do adapt to it, but are likely to have issues integrating it into their worldview. Someone granted sight will struggle with depth perception. Someone who is taught a new language will still instinctively translate things into the fundamentals of their native language. Metahuman abilities seem to come more readily and with fewer handicaps due to preconceptions. This might be a matter of media convenience (who wants to spend ten episodes of the villain-of-the-week slowly figuring out how to dissolve into gas without leaving their clothing behind?). It could be a result of how metahuman powers often correspond to personality or aspects of a person's history such that the person who's always running a little late already kept wishing they could hit a fast-forward button on themselves, the person who felt like the world keeps changing too quickly always wanted a pause button, the person who handled explosives frequently can now initiative those reactions instinctively, etc. Or it could be that something in how the powers works does "cheat" by providing understanding of the power with the power itself.

### Powers do also seem to need a trigger most of the time

A number of characters seem to come into their powers in a time of crisis. Weather Wizard had his plane struck by lightning. Tar Pit was submersed in molten tar. Vibe *died* by having a hand inserted in his chest. The Turtle had the love of his life leaving him. In that moment, grasping for *something* that could be done, they managed to trigger their ability. And, in some cases, it takes a while for it to kick in. Tar Pit didn't awaken from the tar for some time for example. His power let him survive, and it was enough for a time.

### Likely, it's a mix

Based on my viewing of multiple shows, it seems like most powers grant some basic competence at the outset and it then takes some combination of passive use of the power (similar to lifting weights in the gym to build muscle) and active experimentation (trying to twist a bit differently during a flip to maybe land a bit differently), both sometimes spurred by seeing someone else doing something and, now realizing it's possible, taking steps to try to learn it. In the case of Zoom, we know he made some initial use of superspeed, and he pitted himself against multiple metahumans, including at least one speedster, which means he would have many examples of powers that he could try to replicate, or which he could learn by attempting to counter them. And yes, I think that the setting "cheats" a little bit in that the addition of powers seems to have carved certain new bits of physics just waiting to be discovered, although that gets into that old chestnut about how difficult it is to tell whether such interesting quirks are the result of finding interactions of complex systems that came into being semi-randomly, or are the aspects of an intelligently designed system.